# How to replace a word in a blob with the next blob entry of the database table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying building a page which is able to read a table and write the Selected entries (time, sender, recipient, title and content) down which is working perfectly fine.

The problem I'm facing is the first content Entry is a text BLOB like this

```
ex.
TextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextText
img1.jpg
TextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextText
```

the `img1.jpg` is saved in the next content entry saved a BLOB and has to be base64 encoded to be printed as a image and now I'm stuck while trying to write it down like this

```
TextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextText
(actual image from the next entry)
TextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextText
```

I have tried to check with `strpos` if the content contains the filename of the next blob and then to replace that with the actual image but I can't manage to get the next table entry in the same row

Here is the code for the normal output

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, createRequest(true, $link)) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

    $title = $row["a_subject"];
    $time = $row["create_time"];
    $sender = $row["a_from"];
    $reciever = $row["a_to"];
    $body = $row["content"];
    $articleid = $row["id"];

    if (strpos($body, '')){
        $img = "<pre>".'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $body).'"/>'."</pre>"

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo ($time) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($sender) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($reciever) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($title) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $img ?></td>
    <td><a href=<?php echo "http://localhost/php/imageviewer.php?ArticleID=".$row["id"].""?>>Zeige Anhänge</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    } else {
        ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo ($time) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($sender) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($reciever) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($title) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($body)?></td>
    <td><a href=<?php echo "http://localhost/php/imageviewer.php?ArticleID=".$row["id"].""?>>Zeige Anhänge</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
```

Right now I'm checking if the content is an image or just some text and then writing them down. What I want to be happening is that lets say the text content is:

```
text
img1
text
img2
text
img3
```

which my current solution i get 4 html table entries
with the first being

```
text
img1.jpg
text
img2.jpg
text
img3 .jpg
```

the second being

```
actual image of img1.jpg
```

the third being

```
actual image of img2.jpg
```

etc

What i want in the end is one table entry that looks like this

```
text
actual img1
text
actual img2
text
actual img3
```

Comment: What do you call blob exactly?

Comment: The content is saved as Binary Large Objects (BLOBs) or what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Freddy789 can you give us a *real* example of one of your database entries? Also, to clarify, are you saying that you have a single field - presumably `content` - which contains both text and image BLOBs?

Comment: @dunc i changed some things but this is an entry how its saved firstname

address

31234 City

tel number 1111111111111

email@email

 

cid:image001.png@01D4F600.E3F53D80   cid:image002.png@01D4F600.E3F53D80    cid:image003.png@01D4F600.E3F53D80    cid:image004.png@01D4F600.E3F53D80    cid:image005.png@01D4F600.E3F53D80    cid:image006.png@01D4F600.E3F53D80    cid:image007.png@01D4F600.E3F53D80

logo

Comment: @Freddy789 can you try running this code and see if it serves the desired purpose?

`preg_match('/((cid:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)/', $row["content"], $blobs);`

`print_r($blobs);`

Comment: @dunc first of all thanks for answering but when i run your code i get this  
Array ( [0] => cid:image001.png@01D51483.8B092000 [1] => cid:image001.png@01D51483.8B092000 [2] => cid:image001.png@01D51483.8B092000 ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => cid:image001.png@01D5148A.A2A28560 [1] => cid:image001.png@01D5148A.A2A28560 [2] => cid:image001.png@01D5148A.A2A28560 ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) i cut some Array() because of charlimit

Comment: OK, so... are you trying to remove these BLOBs from the `content` field entirely, or are you just wanting to replace them with a correct `<img>` tag so that they display as images?

Comment: Lets say first content Entry is an email with an image now in this database the image get saved in the next content Entry and where the image should be in the email it just says image001.png what i want is that the image001.png gets replaced with the actual image so i have one entry in my html table with the text and image and not 2 seperate entries where one is the text and one the image

Comment: Do you have an actual image file called `image001.png`, and is this file stored in the same directory as your web page?

Comment: @dunc I dont have the file saved locally since its saved in the database the name image001.png is saved under filename ex                                                                 
id: 1 filename: file1.html content: email                                                                            id: 2 filename: image001.img content: converted image string

Comment: Can you give me an example of how the images are stored in the database then please?

Comment: They are saved as BLOB so if i want them to be actual images and not a long string of characters i have to use base64_encode example for not encoded img L�4C�=L�?M�5C�:I�1@�0@�:I�5D�6D�=K�2A�>L�6D�AN�KZ�ES�Q^�BP�M[�L[�R_�KY�FT�GV�@N�AP�Wd�R`�[i�Xe�Wd�Zh�Xc�[h�Sa�Wc�\i�]j�Zg�Ra�\g�Ra�^j�Ua�Yf�T`�Ve�_k�my�hs�mx�iu�ly�ly�ny�lx�oz�ny�w����������Ƙ��Þ�Ş�Ģ�Ǡ�Ǳ�Ҭ�Τ�ʬ�ͫ�ϥ�ɠ�ǯ�и�֩�̦�ɢ�Ǩ�ˬ�ͼ���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������had to cut some characters charlimit

Comment: OK, starting to make sense. Are the images stored as BLOB in a different database table? If so, can you show me its structure?

Comment: They are saved in the same Database table as the Email as ex                                           id: 1 filename: file1.html content: email                                                                      id: 2 filename: image001.img content: L�4C�=L�?M�....

Comment: I'll start writing an answer, but you will have to add some comments to clarify your structure/request I think. Last thing, can you please give me the SQL query you've used to create `$res`?

Comment: $query =  "SELECT `article_attachment`.`id`,`article_attachment`.`filename`,`article_attachment`.`content`
        FROM `article_attachment` 
           WHERE ";   removed unnecessary Selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so from what I can gather, you've got some rows in this table which are actual content that you want to display, including references to some image filenames, then in the same table you have these actual images stored as base64 encoded BLOBs.

Impossible for me to test... so have a play around with it, and see if it offers what you're interested in.

I've commented my additions to make them more clear.

Oh and also I've used `<?=` shorthand purely because I think it makes the code a bit easier to read/more accessible. You obviously don't need to use this if you don't want to!

```
<?php

<<PUT ANY OTHER EXISTING CODE HERE, E.G. THE START OF YOUR SCRIPT>>
$res = mysqli_query($link, createRequest(true, $link)) or die(mysqli_error($link));

// This function serves a dual purpose
// Given an image filename, e.g. `image001.png`, it will search the table for this filename and (hopefully) return a base64 encoded BLOB
// It then decodes this content and returns it
function get_image_from_filename ($filename, $db_connection) {
    $query = "SELECT article_attachment.content FROM article JOIN ticket ON article.ticket_id = ticket.id JOIN article_attachment on article.id = article_attachment.article_id WHERE article_attachment.filename = '$filename'";

    $res = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_connection));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        return base64_decode($row["content"]);
    }
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $title = $row["a_subject"];
    $time = $row["create_time"];
    $sender = $row["a_from"];
    $reciever = $row["a_to"];
    $body = $row["content"];
    $articleid = $row["id"];

    if (base64_encode(base64_decode($body, true)) === $data){
        // If the `$body` can be decoded/encoded successfully, this row is an image - let's skip it
        continue;
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise, let's find all of the references to our images, and look them up in the database

        // This pattern will find the CID references and retrieve the associated image's filename
        $pattern = '/(?:cid:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+/';
        // This is the replacement that will be put into the `$body` variable, using the function at the top of this script
        $replacement = "<pre>" . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . get_image_from_filename('$1', $link) . '" />' . "</pre>";

        $body = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $body);

?>

<tr>
    <td><?=$time?></td>
    <td><?=$sender?></td>
    <td><?=$receiver?></td>
    <td><?=$title?></td>
    <td><?=$body?></td>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/php/imageviewer.php?ArticleID=<?=$articleid?>">Zeige Anhänge</a></td>
</tr>

<?php

    } // End base64 if

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When im using your Code i get multiple notices and warnings. When changing and editing your Code i can rid of all of them except one(Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 107) but even than im not getting any table entries

Comment: Here are all the Notices/Warnings 
Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 38

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 38

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 38

Comment: Now after trying and trying again i managed to get it to work with one problem the replaced img blobs dont show up as image if i use base64_encode it just shows "alt=" and if i use base64_decode it shows the full string

Comment: Could you post the full code that you're now using? Put it on something like https://pastebin.com/ and put the link in here. OR update your original post (just put the new code at the end - don't overwrite the original).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RGkMz6K5 with this code it still does table entries with img blobs but it also replaces the image001.img with the img blob it just doesnt shows as a image

Comment: OK so the change you've made there won't work. You're trying to `base64_encode` content that doesn't exist. Can you please run this query and tell me if its output? `SELECT article_attachment.content FROM article FROM article JOIN ticket ON article.ticket_id = ticket.id JOIN article_attachment on article.id = article_attachment.article_id WHERE article_attachment.filename = 'image001.png'`

Comment: With that query the output is still the same

Comment: Sorry, I meant, can you put the output in here :) E.g. run the query on PHPMyAdmin or whatever so I can make sure the query is working properly and giving the expected output.

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin there seems to be a different error since im getting #1030 - Got error 12 from storage engine           when i run that query. When i looked at the output of my html table again i also realized that the replaced string isnt the image anyway

Comment: I've just spotted an error in the query. Try running this instead: `SELECT article_attachment.content FROM article JOIN ticket ON article.ticket_id = ticket.id JOIN article_attachment on article.id = article_attachment.article_id WHERE article_attachment.filename = 'image001.png'`

Comment: Doh! Could you try updating your code to use the code in my answer? I've changed the query there - let's see what happens.

Comment: Im getting these Notices and no Entry in the html table 
Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 88

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 88

Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 88

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 88

Comment: getting these two notices now and still no entry in html table after using you updated code
Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 107

Warning: mysqli_query(): (HY000/1030): Got error 12 from storage engine in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\messagehistory.php on line 91
Got error 12 from storage engine

Comment: `Error 12 from storage engine` means your database server has run out of memory. If you're developing locally, you may need to restart your computer and try again?

Comment: the database im working on is on a server and i dont think i can make any changes on that.. but more importantly the error only appears when i use the function    get_image_from_filename whenever im not using it i get 'normal' results not the ones i want but its there are no problems on the databases end

Comment: Morning @Freddy789. Would you be able to set up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for me containing some information about your database? That would be the best way to move forward here.

Comment: I eventually found the solution to the problem myself and kind of forgot about my SO question however without your help it would probably have taken me much longer. I will accept your answer as it was the most useful one (and only one lol).